# Listening to Song End in just_audio

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I wanna ask is there any stream to listen when the song get ended to do some stuff at that point in [just_audio flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) or is there any method to do that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, [AudioPlayer](https://pub.dev/documentation/just_audio/latest/just_audio/AudioPlayer-class.html) instances have a field called [playerState](https://pub.dev/documentation/just_audio/latest/just_audio/AudioPlayer/playerState.html) or [playerStateStream](https://pub.dev/documentation/just_audio/latest/just_audio/AudioPlayer/playerStateStream.html) (If you want to listen for events). playerStateStream can be listened to using the stream which has a field called [processingState](https://pub.dev/documentation/just_audio/latest/just_audio/PlayerState/processingState.html). This field contains all the information you require ([Here is the list](https://pub.dev/documentation/just_audio/latest/just_audio/ProcessingState-class.html)). If the processing state is completed, then the player has finished playing.

---

Example:

```
_player.playerStateStream.listen((playerState) {
    if (playerState.processingState == ProcessingState.completed) {
        // Some Stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but don't understand very well tested it but getting problems, Can you show an example ?

Comment: Please add some code of the widget in which you are trying to listen to the end event.

Comment: ```_player.playerStateStream.listen((state) {
      if (state == ProcessingState.completed) { // Some Stuff
        } else { // Some Other Stuff }
    });```
In a function which get called on initializing state

Comment: Yes. Dont forget to dispose the stream subscription in void dispose

Comment: I have already disposed the player but error it shows a red wavy line on the ```state == ProcessingState.completed```

Comment: I did not notice the mistake in your comment. I have updated the answer. try it

Comment: Ok I got my mistake in if statement I have wrote ```state``` except ```state.processingState``` Now working thanks bro 

Answer (score 1):

To enhance the Afridi's answer: one can subscribe to another stream, `playbackEventStream`, to get updates for individual audio sources in a playlist. This is an example how to update the song name:

```dart
player.playbackEventStream.listen((e) => updateCurrentSong());
...
void updateCurrentSong() {
  setState(() {
    final int index = player.currentIndex ?? 0;
    currentSong = "${player.audioSource?.sequence[index].tag}";
  });
}
```